How to properly set my setting.py file when using django-mongoengine with Django Rest Framework?
I'm trying to make my first migration using django and django-mongoengine.
I'm rather new to the topic.
When i launch my first python manage.py makemigrations, I get the following error:
AttributeError: module 'mongoengine' has no attribute 'mongo_admin'
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mongoengine.mongo_admin'

Here is my INSTALLED_APPS list
INSTALLED_APPS
when I comment #'mongoengine.mongo_admin'
I get the following error:
Error when commenting mongoengine.mongo_admin
Here is my pip list result:
(venv) PS C:\Users\sabat\Documents\Diginamic\Stage\CampingBack\Camping\WebCamping> pip list
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- --------
asgiref                            3.8.1
blinker                            1.7.0
build                              1.2.1
certifi                            2024.2.2
charset-normalizer                 3.3.2
click                              8.1.7
colorama                           0.4.6
Django                             3.0
django-admin-honeypot-updated-2021 1.2.0
django-axes                        5.27.0
django-browserid                   2.0.2
django-classy-tags                 3.0.1
django-cors-headers                3.11.0
django-cors-middleware             1.5.0
django-environ                     0.11.2
django-filter                      21.1
django-ipware                      4.0.2
django-missing                     1.1.0
django-mongo-auth                  0.1.3
django-mongoengine                 0.4.6
django-sekizai                     3.0.1
djangorestframework                3.15.1
dnspython                          2.6.1
environ                            1.0
idna                               3.6
Markdown                           3.6
mongoengine                        0.27.0
oauthlib                           3.2.2
packaging                          24.0
panda                              0.3.1
pip                                23.2.1
pip-tools                          7.4.1
pymongo                            4.6.3
pyproject_hooks                    1.0.0
pytz                               2024.1
requests                           2.31.0
requests-oauthlib                  1.3.1
setuptools                         65.5.0
sqlparse                           0.4.4
tweepy                             4.14.0
urllib3                            2.2.1
wheel                              0.43.0

I haven't find any informations on this topic in the doc of mongoengine.
Should I use a less recent version of django or other version of mongoengine and/or django-mongo-auth and/or django-mongoengine? Or is anybody has a working project with mongoengine and DRF with a settings.py I could check?
Any piece of advice is welcome.
Thanks.
I'm just trying to execute python manage.py makemigrations with MongoDB as my database in Django Rest Framework. I'm currrently using python 3.12 interpreter.
